# db:seed not loading models

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rake

I'm trying to seed my database with the standard `db/seeds.rb` method. This works fine on my development machine, but on my server, I get:

```
$ sudo rake db:seed RAILS_ENV=production --trace
** Invoke db:seed (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute db:seed
rake aborted!
uninitialized constant Permission
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2503:in `const_missing'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:92:in `const_missing'
/path/.../.../.../.../db/seeds.rb:4
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.4/lib/tasks/databases.rake:215:in `load'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.4/lib/tasks/databases.rake:215
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `call'
...
```

But when I check in the console, the model does exist:

```
$ script/console production
Loading production environment (Rails 2.3.4)
>> Permission
=> Permission(id: integer, ..., created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)
```

What am I forgetting?

Comment: Note that it DOES work fine in development environment on my production server.

Comment: How does your seeds.rb look like?

Comment: I fixed it. I disabled `threadsafe!`.

Comment: please add your answer and mark it as answered.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It can be fixed by disabling `threadsafe!` in the environment configuration.

Answer (score 10):

In a comment to the blog posted linked to above and here again: http://www.builtfromsource.com/2011/02/09/getting-rake-dbseed-and-config-threadsafe-to-play-nice/

Bruce Adams mentions that one can call:

config.threadsafe! unless $rails_rake_task

to only turn on threadsafe when not running a rake task.

But as the issue is really that threadsafe turns off dependency_loading, you can simply add this line after config.threadsafe! to leave it enabled, but still load your environment as you expect.

config.dependency_loading = true if $rails_rake_task

Answer (score 2):

I just ran across a good approach to this problem [in this article](http://www.builtfromsource.com/2011/02/09/getting-rake-dbseed-and-config-threadsafe-to-play-nice/). I'll summarize here so people can (hopefully) find it quicker.

The idea is to turn off threadsafe in the production environment, first by editing config/environments/production.rb:

```
config.threadsafe! unless ENV['THREADSAFE'] == 'off'
```

You then set THREADSAFE=off when running rake tasks.