# What code runs when a Rails application is started?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

is there an event I can write some code for when a Rails application is first started? I want to make sure my administrator user exists whenever the app starts. I am using devise auth framework in case that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be better to make a new user in `seeds.rb` and run `rake db:seed` before starting the application - that's what it's for.

Comment: I thought, probably mistakenly, that this only sets up the test db? From reading it seemed that he wants this behavior in production as well?

Comment: @jaydel - No, that's generally handled by fixtures.

Comment: interesting. We are using factory girl and we have several tables that hold constants and we seed those in seeds.rb. I wonder if someone here had to purposely set something up to get that behavior.

Comment: so as a follow on question, db/seeds.rb doesn't do anything to our production or development databases--I'm assuming we've got a setting somewhere that controls this. I know this to be true because a coworker yesterday put new seed data in that file and it worked in our rspec units but failed when simply using the app.

Comment: @jaydel - this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2204936/dbseed-not-loading-models

Answer (score 0):

You could probably make an initializer inside of `config/initializers`. You have to make sure you load up devise first, though.